# Did two crisis actors both claim to be the father of the same child killed in the Uvalde, Texas shooting?

Tags: united-states, criminology

A friend-of-a-friend posted a BitChute video on my friend's Facebook wall: [*Two crisis actor "fathers" share the same daughter in Uvalde, Texas*](https://www.bitchute.com/video/eYZhmhMAJbmj/)

The description states:

> NBC and CNN interview two different crisis actors who claim to be the same biological father of the same girl. They show the same pictures of the same girl. No tears whatsoever.

The video shows two news segments from NBC and CNN of two different men, each interviewed about their daughter who was killed in the [Robb Elementary School shooting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robb_Elementary_School_shooting) in Uvalde, Texas. The pictures of the daughter appear to be the same girl.

The title card at 53s states:

> Now, CNN's Anderson Cooper interviews another crisis actor who claims to be the "father" of the same girl in the NBC video

The video goes on to state "Neither students, nor teachers, died in Texas", but that isn't the claim I would like to focus on.

Are there two men claiming to be the biological fathers of the same daughter? Is one or both a [crisis actor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crisis_actor#Conspiracy_theories_and_defamation)?

Comment: Note that a claim about the use of "crisis actors" was part of the libel of Alex Jones against the Sandy Hook victims, which he lost in court: https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-59298320 ; it's an exceptionally vile form of libel, almost but not quite on the level of genocide denial.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136757/discussion-on-question-by-oddthinking-did-two-crisis-actors-both-claim-to-be-the).

Answer (score 313):

There are indeed two different segments by [CNN](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xvPOGcHrpRU) and [NBC](https://youtu.be/TIhUoeeV52o?t=166) that show an interview with two different men identified as the father of Amerie Jo Garza.

- It is clear that both segments are talking about the same girl with both segments showing a picture of the girl hold an honor roll certificate with her name [here](https://youtu.be/xvPOGcHrpRU?t=13) and [here](https://youtu.be/TIhUoeeV52o?t=278).
- The men in the different segment are clearly different people. Besides obvious appearance, the father in the CNN segment is identified as "Angel Garza", the father in the NBC segment is identified as "Alfred Garza III".

Contrary to the claim in the video clip from the OP, neither segment  ever claims that either of the interviewed men are the *biological* father of the child. In fact, the [obituary for Amerie Jo Garza](https://www.hillcrestmemorialfuneralhome.com/obituaries/Amerie-Garza/#!/Obituary) states:

> Amerie Jo Garza, 10, of Uvalde died May 24, 2022 at Robb Elementary School in Uvalde, Texas.
>
> Visitation will take place on Monday, May 30, 2022 from noon to 9:00 p.m. at Hillcrest Memorial Funeral Home where a Rosary will take place at 6:00 P.M. Mass is set for Tuesday, May 31, 2022 at 2:00 p.m. at Sacred Heart Catholic Church.
>
> She was born on May 10, 2012 in Uvalde, Texas to Kimberly Garcia and
> Alfred Garza III.
>
> She is survived by **her father, Alfred Garza III** and companion Viviana
> Granados, of Uvalde; mother, Kimberly Garcia and **step-father Angel
> Garza**, of Uvalde; One brother, Zayne Garza, of Uvalde; Grandparents
> Alfredo Garza Jr., Dora Mendoza and husband Fidencio Garcia, Berlinda
> and husband Ponciano Arreola and all of Uvalde, Joe Garza and wife
> Gracie of El Campo; Five Aunts Laura Garza, Vivian Garcia, Victoria
> Garcia, Desirae Garza, all of Uvalde; Sara Garza of El Campo; Five
> Uncles Jose Martinez, Fidencio Garcia Jr. both of Uvalde; Christopher
> Carbajal of Reading, Pennsylvania; Joe Garza Jr. and Jeremy Garza,
> both of El Campo and numerous cousins.
>
> She is preceded in death by Grandparents Ruby Garza, Alfredo Garza
> Sr., Anita Garza, Emma Mendoza, Valente Mendoza and Gilberto Garcia;
> Great-Grandparents Delfino Vasquez and Viviana T. Vasquez
>
> Pallbearers Jose Salinas, Vale Mendoza, Jose Martinez, Jose Chavez,
> Issac Esparza, all of Uvalde; Joe Garza Jr., of El Campo.
>
> Amerie Jo Garza was a kind, caring, blunt, loving, sweet, sassy and of
> course funny little diva who “hated dresses” but nonetheless; she
> truly had a heart of gold. She loved to eat at Chick-Fil-A and vanilla
> bean frape from Starbucks. Her favorite hobbies were swimming,
> drawing, and most of all spending time with family. Amerie biggest
> dream was to become an Art teacher due to her ambitions for
> creativity. A protector of her brother and as we now know her
> classmates. This world will never have another Amerie. She will truly
> be missed.

(Bolding added for emphasis).

So, yes both men are the girl's father.

Comment: Welcome to the modern world where parents of children get divorced later remarry. Also, welcome to southwest Texas where Garza most likely is a more common surname than Smith or Jones. (Garcia is the Smith and Jones of southwest Texas.) I would normally criticize you for your final editorial sentence, but in this case, I heartily agree with that sentiment.